# Jest mocked promise function return undefined

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

This is my helper function in `src/utils/calls/aws.js`

```js
export const loginCognito = (cognitoUser, authenticationDetails) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: resolve,
      onFailure: reject,
      newPasswordRequired: resolve,
    });
  });
};
```

This is my test file:

```js
import { fireEvent, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import { LoginPage } from "../../../views/LoginPage/LoginPage";
import { renderWithProviders } from "../../__test-utils__/test-utils";
// eslint-disable-next-line jest/no-mocks-import
import { LOCALSTORAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN } from "../../../utils/constants/constant";

const accessToken = "an.access.token";

const promisedResult = {
    "idToken": {
        "jwtToken": "an.access.token",
        "payload": {
            "sub": "354548-5454-c59637523bfd",
            "email_verified": true,
            "iss": "https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_tomahwaf",
            "cognito:username": "john-doe",
            "preferred_username": "john-doe",
            "aud": "client.id.aws",
            "custom:dataInizioContratto": "01/01/2020",
            "event_id": "ee5626d5-ffc2-4ecf-89df-2e1a83c0c174",
            "token_use": "id",
            "auth_time": 1670256322,
            "custom:azienda": "acme",
            "exp": 1670259922,
            "iat": 1670256322,
            "email": "info@example.com"
        }
    },
    "refreshToken": {
        "token": "a.refresh.token"
    },
    "accessToken": {
        "jwtToken": "an.access.token",
        "payload": {
            "sub": "354548-5454-c59637523bfd",
            "event_id": "ee5626d5-ffc2-4ecf-89df-2e1a83c0c174",
            "token_use": "access",
            "scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin",
            "auth_time": 1670256322,
            "iss": "https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_tomahwaf",
            "exp": 1670259922,
            "iat": 1670256322,
            "jti": "083d4b9a-5042-485b-bb65-c66e8ae5b921",
            "client_id": "client.id.aws",
            "username": "john-doe"
        }
    },
    "clockDrift": 0
};

jest.mock("../../../utils/calls/aws.js", () => ({
  //loginCognito: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve({accessToken: "an.access.token"}))
  //loginCognito: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(promisedResult))
  //loginCognito: jest.fn(() => promisedResult)
  loginCognito: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(promisedResult)
}));

describe("Test LoginPage", () => {

  it("Can press button without userEvent", async () => {

    renderWithProviders(<LoginPage />);

    const inputUsername = screen.getByLabelText(/username/i);
    fireEvent.change(inputUsername, {
      target: {
        value: "info@example.com",
      },
    });

    const inputPassword = screen.getByLabelText(/password/i);
    fireEvent.change(inputPassword, {
      target: {
        value: "thisIsASecretPassword",
      },
    });

    const loginButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /login/i });
    fireEvent.click(loginButton);
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(localStorage.getItem(LOCALSTORAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN)).toEqual(
        accessToken
      );
    });
  });
});
```

In the real file (LoginPage) I have

```js
const handleClick = async () => {
    // Fetch the data from cognito
    const {cognitoUser, authenticationDetails} = loginCognitoUser(currentItem);
    // Call AWS
    try {
      const isLogged = await loginCognito(cognitoUser, authenticationDetails);
      console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", JSON.stringify(isLogged))
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  };
```

For real implementation it works, but when I call from the test I get

```bash
console.log
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> undefined

at handleClick (src/views/LoginPage/LoginPage.js:52:15)
```

Doesn't mock of a function "bypasses" it returning what I want?

I have made 4 tests, I don't know anymore what to do:

```js
//loginCognito: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve({accessToken: "an.access.token"}))
  //loginCognito: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(promisedResult))
  //loginCognito: jest.fn(() => promisedResult)
  loginCognito: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(promisedResult)
```

I tried add a console.log inside my aws function and... If I remove the mocked I have the console.log, so I think that function is correctly mocked but cannot have the return.

### Edit nr. 2

I tried another thing:

```js
export const loginCognito = () => {
  return "ciao"
}
```

And in test:

```js
jest.mock("../../../utils/calls/aws.js", () => ({
  loginCognito: jest.fn().mockReturnValue("addio")
}));
```

The page under test has console.log undefined!

```js
try {
      //const isLogged = await loginCognito(cognitoUser, authenticationDetails);
      const isLogged = loginCognito();
      console.log("==========", isLogged)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
```

Am I that I don't know how mock it works?

```bash
Console

    console.log
      ========== undefined

      at handleClick (src/views/LoginPage/LoginPage.js:55:15)
```

I need to bypass totally the AWS funciton...

Comment: The second edit looks like `jest.mock` never runs or mocks a wrong file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really speak for why your code is not working, but this is how I would go about writing your test:

```js
// import the function you want to mock
import { loginCognito } from "../../../utils/calls/aws.js";

// tell jest to mock your module
jest.mock("../../../utils/calls/aws.js");

// before each test, mock the implementation
beforeEach(() => {
  loginCognito.mockResolvedValue(...);
});

// cleanup after each test
afterEach(() => {
  loginCognito.mockClear(...);
});
```

If you're using typescript, you will need to make typescript aware that the method is mocked. This is done by casting the method, which is mostly a tedium required for typescript. As a matter of convention, I usually put the work "mock" in front of the name:

```
const mockLoginCongnito = loginCognito as jest.MockedFunction<typeof loginCognito>;
```